How can I get the clip played with "PlayOneShot()"?
I want to gather the played AudioClip.
We can get the source name using the script below, but I can't get the clip. (Log says the clip is null)
How can I get the played clip and its name?
public AudioSource source;
public AudioClip[] clips; //we have clip1 and clip2

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
    {
        int i = Random.Range(0, 1);
        source.PlayOneShot(clips[]);
    }
    if(source.isPlaying)
    {
        Debug.Log(source.gameObject.name); //OK
        Debug.Log(source.clip.name); //Not OK...(null)
    }
{

I want to use the clip in other system.

thats because playoneshot doesnt set the current clip to be the one specified, it just plays it as one shot
